# Making a community wiki question from 2 book exercises

Tags: discussion, soft-question

In Kaplansky's Set Theory & Metric Spaces, there is a section containing 19 exercises on Functions. The first two exercises describe one-to-one and onto properties. Can I make a community wiki page in this Q&A style?

Comment: Related (to the general idea): [Views on asking and answering questions solely to make results available on stack exchange.]

Comment: As far as this specific suggestion is concerned, some of them might already have answers here. For example one of those exercises is about composition of two surjective map; see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22572/injective-and-surjective-functions) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75246/surjectivity-of-composition-of-surjective-functions).

Answer (score 4):

It is no longer possible to ask Community Wiki questions: see the StackExchange blog post [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/):

> **Community Wiki is primarily for Answers**
>
> If we haven’t said this enough already, questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki. What about answers? We removed the ability for users to make a question community wiki, but left the ability for users to make an answer wiki.

...

> Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration. That’s when community wiki shines. If your site is teeming with community wiki posts — particularly in questions — you should consider the above points carefully.

---

That said, even if it were possible, I think it's a bad idea to ask 19 questions at once (whether in a single post or not).  I suggest you ask a single question, learn from it, then ask another question if necessary.

Comment: Does that mean we have to start closing soft questions with no correct answer?

Comment: Although it is true, that you cannot make a question community wiki when posting, the standard procedure is to flag the question for moderators' attention and ask them to convert it to CW, see [CW FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Hm, I didn't know CW on questions was intended to be used so sparingly. Good to know this convention.